# Python Tkinter <Motion> Lag: Canvas Line Following Cursor

Tags: python, events, canvas, tkinter

I'm creating a graphing program using `tkinter.Canvas`.

I have a graph cursor - a vertical line - that follows the mouse cursor.
(This allows the user to view interpolated values on the graph).

However, I have an issue:  **the cursor line lags behind the mouse position**. If the mouse is moved quickly, the cursor disappears until the mouse slows down.

The cursor is set up as follows:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

def GetCursorCoords(pos):
    return (pos, 0, pos, root.winfo_height())

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill = 'both')

cursor = canvas.create_line(*GetCursorCoords(0))

def OnMove(event):
    x = event.x
    canvas.coords(cursor, *GetCursorCoords(x))

canvas.bind('<Motion>', OnMove)

root.mainloop()
```

I have a feeling that this is caused by the cursor line shrinking when being moved.
When the cursor line width is increased (eg. `canvas.create_line(*GetCursorCoords(0), width = 20`), it does not disappear completely when moved; it just looks visibly thinner.

How can I fix this?

(Running Windows 10, Python 3.8.1, Tcl/Tk 8.6)

Comment: Works for me without **lag**. [Edit] your question and show your Python and OS version. The only i can think of are [limit-the-number-of-events-generated-by-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58906587/how-to-limit-the-number-of-events-generated-by-widget) and you use no `__main__` entry point.

Comment: it works fast enough on Linux Mint 19.2 (based Ubuntu 18.04), Python 3.76, Tk/Tcl 8.6 - even if I use `width=20` and add horizontal line.

Comment: The line never disappears for me, and seems reasonably performant on OSX.

Comment: @Tom: Seems a **Windows 10** issue, all other comments using `X`. Which Python Environment/Package you are using? Do you running the exact code in question?